# How to use IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For the last few days, I have been playing around with Asp.net's Identity framework.

I have been able to get the Register and Login working however when I try to extend the functionality to saving data against specific users, I find it is different to how I would normally implement it with stock standard EF.

Normally I would use something like below to save data:

```
using(var context = myDbContex())
{
   context.Add(object);
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, when I try to use this approach after inheriting the IdentityDbContext it is expecting an argument. Is it okay for me to create a default constructor that doesn't take any arguments or should I be passing something in?

My Context currently looks like this:

```
public class AppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        //I am not really sure why options needs to be specified as an argument   
        public AppContext(DbContextOptions<AppContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Xxxxx> Xxxxx { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Yyyyy> Yyyyy { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Zzzzz> Zzzzz { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options =>
                                                        options.UseSqlite("Data Source=App.db"));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        });
```

Why is this implementation of the context different to the standard dbContext, and how can I save data using this context?

Thanks

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core? Please don't tag both

Comment: Yes and please provide code of how your register your db-context and identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this line

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=App.db"));
```

You need to provide a constructor that has the DbContextOptions as paramter, which has nothing todo with IdentityDbContext.

You have two choices now.

Use dependency injection, that is how you are supposed to use it anyway

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   private AppContext context;

   public MyController(AppContext context)
   {
      this.context = context;
   }
}
```

Secondly you could register your context differently.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>();
```

And apply changes in your context, remove the constructor and override `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)`

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=App.db");
}
```

Now you can use it as  you usually would do.

```
using(var context = new AppContext())
{
   // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**:

Not part of the actual question but signin, registration and role managing is handled by these classes, that can be injected when using IdentityDbContext

- [SignInManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
- [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0)
- [RoleManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.rolemanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: Great thanks. It seems like I have some reading to do around dependency injection!

Comment: Yay is a new thing, even for Microsoft :P
Here is a good read about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection

Keep in mind DI and IoC are two different things.

Comment: This fails to answer the most important part of the question: whenever you need to get or change information about users/roles, use `UserManager<T>`, `RoleManager<T>` and `SignInManager<T>`. **DON'T** use the context directly. @Corey please do take this into account

Comment: No it doesn't bc this was not his question. Read the question properly again.

Comment: Updated the answer as a hint for others.

Comment: Thanks @SamiAI90. This question was directly related to saving files and other information to specific user profiles. I am trying to save files associated with a user and the methods that handle that functionality use UserManager, RoleManager, and SignInManager.